# Don't understand the topic of how interfaces can be used as APIs as mentioned in the java tutorials. Don't get the ahaa moment

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface

I am having difficulty getting the "ahaaa" moment when trying to understand interfaces in java.
As per the java tutorials site, in the interfaces section they say:

> Typically, a company sells a software package that contains complex
>   methods that another company wants to use in its own software product.
>   An example would be a package of digital image processing methods that
>   are sold to companies making end-user graphics programs. The image
>   processing company writes its classes to implement an interface, which
>   it makes public to its customers. The graphics company then invokes
>   the image processing methods using the signatures and return types
>   defined in the interface. While the image processing company's API is
>   made public (to its customers), its implementation of the API is kept
>   as a closely guarded secret—in fact, it may revise the implementation
>   at a later date as long as it continues to implement the original
>   interface that its customers have relied on.

My question is related to the explanation above.
When they say: `Typically, a company sells a software package that contains complex methods that another company wants to use in its own software product`

I'm confused. Lets say I have interface defined and I have my implementation classes implementing that interface. How would my customers, use the API that I am creating? Its not like they have access to my implementation classes because as per the description above, `implementation of the API is kept as a closely guarded secret`. So does this mean that all I provide to my customer's is an interface defined with many methods. And the actual implementation needs to be done by the customer? Please shed some light on this whole concept and use of an interface. I don't quite get it. Thanks and sorry for the noob question

Comment: interfaces are just a contract. If you know the interface, you know what result to expect without having access to the actual implementation. The customer has the compiled code, but he cannot see it and knows the interface.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you provide an example?

Comment: A common issue is to assume something is much more than it is.  It must have some magical properties when really it is very simple and it is how you use it which gives it usefulness.  `interface`s are very simple by design.  They are list a bunch of methods an implementation must implement. (and a few constants) There isn't more to it than that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about having the "ahaa moment".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe an example can help.

Assume you have the following classes/interfaces:

```
public interface ImageApi {
   Image create(int width, int height, Color c);
}

class ImageApiImpl implements ImageApi {
    @Override
    public Image create(int width, int height, Color c) {
       ... // implementation
    }    
} 

public ImageApiFactory {
    public static ImageApi getImageApi() {
        return new ImageApiImpl();
    }
}
```

A client would be able to use this Api in the following way:

```
ImageApi api = ImageApiFactory.getImageApi();
Image image = api.create(128, 128, Color.Blue);
```

Now let's assume that the company developing this API finds a faster way of creating images. Unfortunately the new approach works only on windows systems. They would be able to do the following:

```
class FastImageApiImpl implements ImageApi {
    @Override
    public Image create(int width, int height, Color c) {
       ... // faster windows specfic implementation
    }    
} 

public ImageApiFactory {
    public static ImageApi getImageApi() {
        if (isWindowsSystem()) {
            return new FastImageApiImpl();
        }
        return new ImageApiImpl();
    }
}
```

The client code stays the same because both API implementations share the same interface. The client doesn't know about the specific implementation.

Comment: Thank you. This is a wonderful example that shows how a possible API can be designed via exposing the interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

A good example of using just an interface and not knowing about the implementation is Java JDBC which is uses to interact with databases (query, insert, delete, update etc).

Once a connection to a database is made (which I will explain later), The user has a reference to a `Connection` instance which is an interface.  The interface has methods to create various kinds of SQL Statements (which are factory methods) that return implementations of the `Statement` interface which when executed return implementations of the `ResultSet` interface etc.

From a user point of view all these objects are interacted with only through the interface. The user doesn't know or care what the actual class name or implementation details are.

Each Database company has their own proprietary way of implementing general database functions that they would not want to share with outsiders. The creators of Java can't possibly implement EVERY possible database implementation for every kind of database and definitely can not make implementations for types of Databases that didn't exist yet when JDBC was written (or will exist in the future).

Therefore, Java doesn't come with any implementations of JDBC interfaces, just the interface definitions.  If you want to use JDBC to communicate with a particular database, you need to provide an additional jar file which contains that database's implementations of the interface.  Once those jars are on the classpath, you can register that implementation with the JDBC `DriverManager` so it knows which implementations to use.

This has an extra bonus of being able to change database implementations very easily without changing any code that uses JDBC `Connection`s or `Statement`s or `ResultSet`s, you just give the DriverManager a new jar.  (this is assuming your statements don't use non-standard SQL that is only supported by some database companies)